# Connecting to Server with Self Signed Certificate

Tags: java, ssl

Our system is attempting to connect securely to a client's UAT server; they have sent me their system's certificate, intermediate certificate, and root certficate. Their root certificate is self-signed.

I have attempted the following configurations in my Java truststores:

1. Added all 3 certificates to the truststore with "trustcacerts" option
2. Added the intermediate and root to the truststore with "trustcacerts" option
3. Added the root certificate to the cacerts file in /lib/security
   with trustcacerts option, then added the server and intermediate
   certificates to truststore with "trustcacerts" option

I am receiving the following exception when attempting to connect:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
  sun.secuvalidator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
  sun.security.providetpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
    unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

When I added only the root certificate to the truststore, I received the following error:

```
No issuer certificate for certificate in certification path found.
```

Also, I have inspected the certificates and they seem to line up into a certificate chain.

Does anyone know what I have missed or haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You have to include both the Root and Intermediate certificate in the cacerts file in jre/lib/security.